# Titanium HTTPCLIENT can't upload file

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, httpclient

I try to use Brower can upload a file, but if I use Titanium upload, it doesn't work,
the brower code is 
Brower upload file:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Upload.php file:

```
$tmp_file=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$target_file=basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, "files/".$target_file);
```

my titanium code is:

```
var webaddress = 'http://' + address.value + ':' + port1.value + '/scanbatch/index.php';
xhr.open('POST',webaddress);
xhr.send({files : Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'scanbatch.txt')});
```

it can work but the webservice didn't received anything, just received a header.

and by the way , I can send out the short xml through the httpclient ,but if the xml be longer sometime it can't send out, more longer more fail，I mean not always, if the xml longer than 512KB, It always fail.

my code is

```
var webaddress = 'http://' + address.value + ':' + port1.value + '/liveho/scanbatch';   
xhr.open('POST',webaddress);
xhr.send(xmlscript);
```

my onload function is

```
onload : function(e) {  
            alert(this.responseText);   
        },
```

please help me thank you

Answer (score 0):

I will give you some advice, to narrow down the problem (Titanium side).

Have you tested if the path to the file is correct?

```
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory + 
    Ti.Filesystem.getSeparator() + 'scanbatch.txt');

if(file.size)
    xhr.send({files : file});
else
    Ti.API.info("File " + file.nativePath + " doesn't exist or is empty");
```

If it isn't the correct path, try to find it in the resourcesDirectory:

```
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + 
    Ti.Filesystem.getSeparator() + 'scanbatch.txt');
```

Your problem with disconnections might be diminish setting the timeout property. A onerror function could also help you find the problem. The [onsendstream](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-property-onsendstream) property will let you know the progression of the upload.

```
Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
...
    onload : function(e) {  
        alert(this.responseText);   
    },
    onerror : function(e) {  
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        alert(e.error);  
    },
    onsendstream : function(e) {  
        var progress = parseFloat(e.progress)*100;
        Ti.API.info("Upload progress:" + progress + "%");
        //e.progress will contain a value from 0.0-1.0 with the progress of the upload
        alert("Upload progress:" + progress + "%"); 
    },
    timeout : 5000  // in milliseconds
...
});
```

Comment: Thank you ,but the path is correct, and my timeout property is 35000

Comment: and the webservice always feedback me in very short time. the error just depend on my filesize, I don't know why

Comment: In which case, this case: `xhr.send(xmlscript);`      
or this other: `xhr.send({files : file});` ?

Comment: the onload function is same, just different button ,one send file ,one send xml, timemout property is same, in xml case i can send small size information. if  the size change to bigger it can't. the file case's problem is i can send small size file to the webservice wrote by c#, but if the file size change to bigger, it can't received. so i use the apache wrote a webservice , the code is at up filed. it can't send any thing to there, just header

Comment: To change the content-type you have to change the request header before calling `xhr.send`, this way: `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");`
Could you confirm if changing the Content-Type to `multipart/form-data` works for a xml larger than 512kb?

Comment: thank you , i found the problem , the mobile device send information will delay , so the problem is not my mobile code, just need to set the webservice waiting time, thank you